# I want to deploy a resource-sharing solution on my company network for 4 gpu-equipped servers. What are my options if I stick with Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, openstack, cloud

Is Openstack a good solution for this? Or is it overkill?

There are 4 servers on the network, each server having 8 NVIDIA 1080ti GPUs.

Basically the use-case would be :

1. User creates a virtual instance.
2. User logs into the virtual instance from their network.
3. User is able to run gpu-accelerated software like Tensorflow on the NVIDIA GPU card.
4. User should be able to store data on the instance.

I guess you would call it a private cloud? But I need these instances to be able to access GPU resources. (1-8 gpus at least)

My 4 servers have Ubuntu installed on them. But I see the openstack instructions when I deploy a private cloud it is MAAS (metal as a service). Is this correct? Because bare metal as I understand it refers to hardware that has no OS.

I'm quite new to this, forgive me if I'm asking the obvious.